# Dialog Android para salir de la app

Tags: java, android, app, aplicación-movil

intento hacer un dialogo que se muestre cuando acabe la partida que me permita que si le de click a reiniciar me reinicie la partida y otro por si le da a salir se cierre la app. Pero todo el rato me salta un error y no me permite ejecutarlo.  He buscado y he visto que con finish puedes cerrar la app, pero me salta en rojo.

```
public void DialogMotrar(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Volver a jugar");
        builder.setMessage("Quieres volver a jugar o salir?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Reiniciar",ReiniciarPartida());
        builder.setNegativeButton("Salir",finish());
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes llamar las functiones directamente. Tienes que crear una instancia de DialogInterface.OnClickListener o usar lambdas:

```
builder.setPositiveButton("Reiniciar", (dialog, which) -> ReiniciarPartida());
builder.setNegativeButton("Salir", (dialog, which) -> finish());
```

Por cierto, los nombres de las funciones no deberían empezar con mayuscula.